# Auto refresh Google Map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, refresh

I'm looking for a method to my Google map auto refresh for each "n" seconds, now i'm refreshing all page, but i must to refresh only the map,

follow my JS code:

```
var DEFAULT_ZOOM = 14;
        function initialize() {
            var map;

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-19.0, -59.0);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: parseInt(getCookie("zoom_gm")),
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            initMarkers(map);
            var zm = DEFAULT_ZOOM;              

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', 
                function(){
                    zm = map.getZoom();
                    setCookie("zoom_gm", zm);
                }
            );
        }
```

Comment: what do you want to refresh inside the map?

Comment: Simultaneously, my system, must display the map and receive new coordinates, the i must show this coordinates on screen as they arrive.

Comment: And how/where you receive the new ccordinates?

Comment: Through a ruby variable, using a block like this >> " <% RoR here %> ", and sending this value to my JS using this code: http://pastebin.com/V3KUPN4q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to retrieve the new data using AJAX. Once you received the data, you have to walk the array/object you've received and add the new [Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#Marker). Depending on what you receive(maybe the response contains coordinates you've already set) you need to remove existing markers by using `markerObj.setMap(null)` .

That's all I can suggest so far, you're very stingy with informations.

Comment: i've tried this code >> http://pastebin.com/zPjiGhHJ, but it doesn't refresh the map coordinates when some marker was added. PS.: the code was commented.

Comment: I don't see any AJAX-implementation there

Comment: Can you indicates me some links? I've o idea how to start!